# powershell script with cmd argument

Tags: powershell

i have a simple question!
I want to run the powershell script but, I want a little different way.

how to run powershell script like the script below?

`(python -c 'print "A"*100')`

Is the PowerShell possible?
In conclusion, I want to pass the powershell script with cmd argument 

`like the... 
Powershell.exe -c '$test = 1; $socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('127.0.0.1',31337);'`

Answer (score 2):

try Something like this:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\yourscriptfile.ps1" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: It was a simple method! Thank you for your answer.